# How run reactions on complex structures in MobX Flutter

Tags: flutter, observable, mobx

I try to understand how MobX observes chages. For example:
I have an object called User where I store user data. It is used in multiple places using GetIt singletons. I have general app header where i am observinf user.name by doing this:

```
Observer(builder: (_) => Text(userStore.user.name))
```

and I have page with form where I am editting user info. Changing name looks like:

```
Observer(
          builder: (_) => TextFormField(
                initialValue: _userStore.user.name,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name'),
                onChanged: (value) => _userStore.user.name = value,
              ))
```

So theoreticlly it should not observe shanges because reffrence of User did not change. Theoretically I suppose to use ObservableMap to do this. But this works... Why?

Also when I try to add reaction on **user** object or on **user.name** reactions do not run.

So maybe someone can exmplain me how to run actions on complex structures like maps inside of map?

Answer (score 0):

So at the end of the day I was able to grasp information on how MobX works.

user.name on the header was refreshing because whole page was relbuilding
user object will trigger change if referenc eof object changes
user.name will change if it will be marked as @observable